# Как узнать, является ли символ буквенным

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, символы

У меня есть символьный массив, который я должен полностью проверить. Надо сделать так, чтобы проверялись только буквенные символы, а спец. символы, числа, пробелы и юникод не проверялись.

Как сделать это?

Comment: Самое прямолинейное - это использование стандартной C-функции isalpha

Comment: но скорее всего, если это домашнее задание, подойдет такое `c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'`

Comment: А если это юникод? Что вероятнее...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Можно воспользоваться функцией [std::isalpha](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) .

Рекомендую, также, прочитать [описание](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) на английском cppreference .

Эта функция вернёт ненулевое значение, если аргумент является буквой в текущей локали, если это не буква - вернёт 0. В локали по умолчанию вернёт не ноль (true) для символов: **abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ**.

Пример использования:

```
std::string word;
std::cin >> word;
for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i)
{
    char x = word[i];
    if (std::isalpha((unsigned char)x))
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Другой способ, без использования стандартной библиотеки, но формально он не гарантируется стандартом (хотя на практике, скорее всего, так получится):

```
bool isLetter(char x)
{
    return (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z') || (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z');
}
```

Последний способ не очень хорош, потому что стандарт не гарантирует, что буквы идут по порядку от 'A' к 'Z' (и аналогично для строчных).

Comment: Попробовал isalpha(). Вылетает ошибка уже в самом приложение. Expression: c >= - 1 && c <=255

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, кусок кода, который вылетает с ошибкой. Попробуйте перед вызовом функции привести аргумент к unsigned char: std::isalpha((unsigned char)x)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat всё работает, но после пробела цикл прекращает работать. Т.е. все символы у меня обрабатываются, но как только пробел, программа завершается. При этом все спец. символы и числа пропускаются, как надо

Comment: Вы уверены, что в вашей строке после пробела что-то есть? Если вы читаете строку так: `std::cin >> str;` , то чтение идёт как раз до пробела.

Comment: Как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `std::getline(std::cin, str);`

Comment: Стандарт как раз гарантирует, что буквы будут идти последовательно, только это не стандарт C++ ;)

Comment: Вы упустили один аргумент данного метода cin.getline(string, streamsize, separator);. А так, огромное спасибо!

Comment: @ixSci насколько я помню, про символы нет гарантии непрерывности, а вот про цифры есть на уровне языка. Вы вообще о каком стандарте говорите?

Comment: @älёxölüt, ASCII, конечно же.